# Unable to add tag to transit gateway default route table

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have searched on google and have been trying to add the tag to the transit gateway default route without any success. Here is code i tried:

```
resource "aws_default_route_table" "example" {
  default_route_table_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.association_default_route_table_id}"
  tags = {
    Name = "default table"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The syntax looks correct. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @JohnB No error it is not updating default route table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, this might help someone:

```
data "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "default" {
  filter {
    name   = "default-association-route-table"
    values = ["true"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "transit-gateway-id"
    values = ["${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id}"]
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "tag-default-rt" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 create-tags --resources ${data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.default.id} --tags Key=Name,Value=Default-Route-Table"
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default route table within a VPC is not created nor managed by Terraform. Therefore tagging the default route table is not possible. In my experience it is a 'best practice' to not use default anything within a AWS VPC. Deploy a new VPC, customize it to suit your needs, subnets, tags etc.

A good place to start is to use the official Terraform AWS VPC module. It is very comprehensive and covers just about any use case you can throw at it.

Answer (score -1):

The `aws_default_route_table` is for managing the default route of a VPC.
I believe the resource you want is [ec2_transit_gateway_route_table](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.html)

E.g.

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "example" {
  transit_gateway_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.id}"
  tags = {
    Name = "default table"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not update the default route table for transit gateway. This creates a new route table for that transit gateway.